# Rails 4 Data Modeling

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I´m a Rails newbie and I have the following question:

I need to develop a demo app in order to manage crime alternative penalties (in that case criminals aren't in prison, but they have to do social services for free during an amount of time).

Therefore we have a ***Criminal*** commiting many ***Crimes*** each crime having its own ***Penalty***.

Any suggestions on how to model this using Rails 4?

I really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by using `has_one :through` association read it here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-one-through-association

```
   class Criminal < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :crimes
      has_one :penalty, through: :crime
    end

    class Penalty < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :criminal
      belongs_to :crime
    end

    class Crime < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :criminals
      has_one :penalty, through: :criminal
    end
```

Comment: Thanks, man ! I´m gonna give it a try as soon as possible.  :)

Comment: Don't forget to come back and rate the answer if it helps! ;)